# How to send an email with multiple attachments from Gmail using API client library for .NET

Tags: google-api, gmail-api, google-api-dotnet-client

My app uses [Google API client library for .NET](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/dotnet/apis/gmail/v1) to send emails with attachments.

When using [Send()](https://github.com/google/google-api-dotnet-client/blob/master/Src/Generated/Google.Apis.Gmail.v1/Google.Apis.Gmail.v1.cs#L2787), I'm facing some limitations when it comes to file size of the attachments. So, I guess switching to [Resumable upload](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/guides/uploads) as upload method may help. But it's pretty much undocumented.
Looking into source code, I guess using [different Send() overload](https://github.com/google/google-api-dotnet-client/blob/master/Src/Generated/Google.Apis.Gmail.v1/Google.Apis.Gmail.v1.cs#L2860) may be the way forward, but I can't figure out how to use it properly.

So, instead of attaching the files into message and calling it like this:

```
var gmailResult = gmail.Users.Messages.Send(new Message
{
    Raw = base64UrlEncodedMessage
}, "me").Execute();
```

I should not attach the files to message and do something like following?

```
var gmailResult = gmail.Users.Messages.Send(new Message
{
    Raw = base64UrlEncodedMessage
}, "me", fileStream, contentType).Upload();
```

1. The second version does not return any API error, but does nothing. I'm obviously missing something here.
2. How do I attach more than one attachment?

Answer (score 2):

This is kind of an old question, but putting an answer here just in case anyone else needs it:

I was able to achieve this by converting my mime message into a stream (attachment(s) included), and then calling this overload on Send:

```
UsersResource.MessagesResource.SendMediaUpload googleSendRequest = service.Users.Messages.Send(null, "youremail@gmail.com", mimeMessageStream, "message/rfc822");
IUploadProgress created = googleSendRequest.Upload();
```

This will upload all of the attachments with the email message content and then send it off.  I was able to send two 5 megabyte attachments in an email.  Previously I was not able to send even one of those via the other Send method that takes in a base64 encoded mime message.